# Twilio Android QuickStart app for Programmable Voice - No incoming calls

Tags: twilio, twilio-php, twilio-api

I have followed the guide that says "Get Started with Android" for Twilio Android Programmable Voice SDK.

I have done everything right, from using the correct Account Sid, API Key, API Secret to giving Voice Grant to the access token generated.

I have also added the GCM push SID in order to receive incoming calls in the Quickstart Android App.

However, I am not able to receive calls in my Android app (though it's working fine in the browser)

Based on the code in this app, I have to release an update to my users.

Comment: Are you seeing any errors that you can share? Have you checked the [Twilio debugger](https://www.twilio.com/console/dev-tools/debugger)? What does your TwiML app do?

Comment: TwiML app basically directs the call to a number and a client. I can see the logs in my dashboard, and no warnings or errors are there. Even the echoed TwiML looks absolutely fine to me.

Comment: To my surprise, our current app in production that uses Twilio client Android SDK instead of Twilio Voice SDK is also not receiving any incoming calls however no code change or update has been released. This is really hurting my business right now :(

Comment: @philnash I have been following Twilio documentation and have seen you troubleshooting some of the most complex cases. Will it be good if I can get on a chat room with you to tackle this problem?

Comment: If something has stopped incoming calls to your existing app I recommend you get in touch with [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) and let them know this is high priority. I am also not a specialist in Android, so wouldn't be very useful in a chat. If you get in touch with support they will be able to assist you or find you someone who can.

Comment: @philnash I have already opened a support ticket almost 40 hrs. back and haven't received a reply from Twilio team. I understand that I am on the free plan when it comes to Twilio support and hence I am not under guaranteed response time.

Comment: Can you email me at philnash@twilio.com with your ticket number and I'll see if I can get it looked at.

Comment: @philnash I have opened two tickets. One has got no response since 40 hrs. However, there is a ticket that I opened for the exact same issue around 2 hrs back and it has got a response from twilio team. I am emailing you the latest ticket id - please get it looked. Thanks for your support :)

Comment: @prateek31
Have you done with voip calling in twilio ?

Comment: @PragyaMendiratta I solved this by generating a new push credential and a new project on FCM. Somehow my old push credential was not working. It may also be related to the fact that more than 15 clients were registered for a single client and Twilio doesn't like that.